# React Native npm package causes duplicate name

Tags: react-native, npm, package

I have created npm package. It contains only native code, no other package nothing. After creating it I tried to install it to test project but it causes bug..

```
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: D:\React\test\node_modules\xxx\node_modules\react-native\package.json collides with D:\React\test\node_modules\react-native\package.json

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
```

Here is the list package.json list of my package, I dont know how to solve this issue because I never created package before.

```
{
  "name": "xx",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.53.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "description": "Animated backgrounds for react-native",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/xxx"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "background",
    "animated"
  ],
  "author": "xx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "xx/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "xx#README"
}
```

Comment: Please don't censor your package name with `xx`, it's important here

Comment: hastImpl also causes a name collision [here](https://github.com/aws/awsmobile-cli/issues/190)

Comment: Please don't censor `node_modules\xxx\node_modules`, the content of `xxx` is important here - except in a few cases, you shall not have a `node_modules` folder inside another one

Comment: Its just package name, nothing connected with that..

Comment: Do you use Pods?

Comment: Nope I use dont use that.. I simply created package and installed it to npm thats all..